# How to customize the TextBlock inside the LonglistSelector

Tags: xaml, longlistselector

```XAML
<toolkit:LongListSelector>
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Name="Info" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

I have the above LongListSelector which selects the "Name"(Binded in the first Textblock )values from a list. I also wanted to additional text to it,for which i created one more Textblock below that. I couldn't add the text to the second TextBlock like(Info.Text="HI") because it is inside the LonglistSelector

How to give the values to the second Textblock??

Thanks

Comment: You can bind it to another Property `<TextBlock Name="Info" Text={Binding Whatever}/>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `Info` is a property on the `DataContext` of the page and not on the current item where `Name` is?

If so, you can use a [DataContextProxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) to get to the data outside of the list item. If not, you'll have to be more clear on what you mean.